# Swift value disappeared inside a closure

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
    let context = DBHelper.privateContext()
    context.performBlock({ [weak self] in
        if let ss = self {
            //1. 
            let articles = DBHelper.clientFetchArticles(context) 
            //2. 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                //3. 
                ss.articles = articles
                ss.tableView.reloadData()
                ss.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            })
        }
    })
```

After calling `tableView.reloadData()`, the following code runs:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ArticleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ArticleCell

    #4
    let article = articles[indexPath.row]


    cell.setupWithArticle(article)

    return cell
}
```

`DBHelper.clientFetchArticles` will return `[Article]` with 2 articles (of type ManagedObject).

- At #1, when I print `po articles[0].title`, I get the correct `title` print out.
- At #3, `po articles.count` prints `2`, `po articles[0].title` is also correct
- At #4, `po self.articles[0].title` gets nil.

I have tried `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue())` but still the same result.

Comment: Did you try `po self.articles[0]` at #4?

Comment: yes i have tried it and it's the same (`article` is a property of the view controller)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the `dispatch_async` closure is capturing the values around it but because you aren't modifying the captured value, in this case `articles`, its making a copy of it instead of a reference to that array.

The easy fix would be to make `articles` a property of that class

Link to the [Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID103)

Comment: I tested again and the question was not correct. I have updated my question

Comment: "its making a copy of it instead of a reference to that array." It will always be a copy if it is a native swift `Array`: Swift arrays are structs and structs are value types. It can only be a referecne if he uses `NSArray` / `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: yes, but why is the copied version of `articles` missing properties

Comment: when you copy it doesn't include the nested objects copied unless you explicitly set it up to do that